# php mysql update 1 query instead much more

Tags: php, mysql

i have table with id and sort i need create this update

```
mysql_query("
UPDATE `steps` SET sort = '2' WHERE id = '9' ;
UPDATE `steps` SET sort = '1' WHERE id = '5' ;
UPDATE `steps` SET sort = '3' WHERE id = '6' ;
UPDATE `steps` SET sort = '4' WHERE id = '4' ;
UPDATE `steps` SET sort = '5' WHERE id = '2' ;
UPDATE `steps` SET sort = '6' WHERE id = '1' ;
UPDATE `steps` SET sort = '7' WHERE id = '8' ;
");
```

something like this is incorrect

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `steps` SET sort = '2' WHERE id = '9' , sort = '1' WHERE id = '5' , sort = '3' WHERE id = '6' ;");
```

how can minify it? have you some idea?

Comment: Use `mysql_multi_query()`

Comment: Also please don't use `mysql_*` as it is depreciated.  Instead you should use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Actually, this can be done with a single query - with `CASE`.

Comment: @Itay haha thanks.  So used to typing in `mysqli`

Comment: I would just use multiple UPDATES *within* the same transaction (and with a "multiquery" on a higher latency connection; multiple commands are generally "fine" for low latency). The performance should be "good" and it's fairly readable. Hopefully the update sequence is generated *programmatically* based on an input map so as to avoid much duplication of typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_query` does not support running multiple queries with a single string.  MySQLI has support for this through `mysqli_multi_query`, but I personally think that this is an antipattern.  As far as I know, PDO does not support it.

What you can do is use multiple `mysql_query` statements, but it can also be done in one query:

```
UPDATE steps SET sort = CASE
    WHEN id = 9 THEN 2
    WHEN id = 5 THEN 1
    ELSE sort
END CASE
```

---

Use `PDO` or `mysqli` in new code instead of `ext/mysql`

Comment: PDO doesn't support it indeed, but you could always use an array and loop through it.

Comment: Is MySQL able to use an index on `sort` (should it be present) with a CASE..WHEN?